# Android ListView additional items markered error

Tags: android, listview

I have list view with 78 items, in my activity file I descripe onClick Function realization

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Log.d("Click from activity", "win");
            if(!checkedContacts.contains(clearContacts.get(arg2))){
                checkedContacts.add(clearContacts.get(arg2));
                arg1.setBackgroundColor(R.color.selectedItem);
            } else {
                checkedContacts.remove(clearContacts.get(arg2));
                arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

            }

        }
    });
```

So when I clicked on item it change color. But if I scroll down my listView, other elements every 10 times will have new color. checkedContacts array have right values but, visualization wrong

Comment: you have to save selected item using gettag() method and visualise it  using settag(); method

Comment: here is the full declaration of the fonction : 
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long ident) { }. you can see that the position is actually arg2, so arg1 represent your whole view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that listviews recycle the views that are out of the screen so this way you are not saving the row status. When you get the row out of the screen it will be deleted and when it comes back again it will be refilled in your adapter again.

You may solve this, for example, using your checkedContacts var and make it accesible from your adapter so, if the position given in `getView`function of your adapter you can check if the row has been checked and then youn can change the background color. If the user rotate the screen you may save this var in `onSaveInstanceState` in your activity to recover them later.

Hope it helps :)